# Laravel query to compare two strings from database with a date of format Y-m

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datepicker, eloquent

So I have a table in my database core_companies. In this table I have a column settings which is of type json.
In it I store credit cards for each company. It looks like this: `settings->credit_cards[[0] => {expiration_date: {year: "17", month: "04"}]`
I have two datepickers from which I get in php two dates like this: `"2017-04"`.
What I try to do is return companies whose credit cards expire within a give period, like this (which from obvious reasons doesn't work - it simply ignores my query and returns all companies):

```
if ($key == "expiration_date->date_from" && $value) {
                    $companies = $companies->where("settings->credit_cards->expiration_date", '>=', $value);
                }
                if ($key == "expiration_date->date_to" && $value) {
                    $companies = $companies->where("settings->credit_cards->expiration_date", '<=', $value);
                }
```

So the datepickers are stored in an object `expiration_date`. The first one selects the date from which the comparison starts (the date is stored in $value).
How can I make this query work? How can I compare a date of format Y-m with two separate string from database `{year: "17", month: "04"}` and return credit cards who expire within a given period of time?
Thank you all for your time!

Comment: _In this table I have a column settings which is of type object._    Afaik there is no type object in MySQL???

Comment: Of type json, my bad

Comment: Maybe take a look at this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/. Especially: "Just Because You Can Store JSON … it doesn’t follow you should."

Comment: Why not just store the expiration dates as UNIX timestamp?

Comment: I am sorry it is how they structured this project's database. I just got on this project and I have to work with this structure. I can't save it as unix timestamp because they use these dates in other places in this project by this format that they currently save it in .

Comment: Oh wow, that sucks. Look into `JSON_CONTAINS` and/or `JSON_SEARCH`. I have no experience with JSON in MySQL, but I know you can't just throw it into a where like that, especially not in Laravel. I fear that you need to write a raw query, preferably add one into your Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create parts of your value in date and month and compare with closure in where for ex.

```
if ($key == "expiration_date->date_from" && $value) {
    $parts = explode('-', $value);
    $companies = $companies->where(function($q) use($parts){
        // either year is greater or year is same and month is same or greater
        $q->where("settings->credit_cards->expiration_date->year", '>', $parts[0])
            ->orWhere(function($q) use($parts){
                $q->where("settings->credit_cards->expiration_date->month", '>=', $parts[1])
                    ->where("settings->credit_cards->expiration_date->year", '=', $parts[0]);
            });
    });
}
```

same goes for date_to filter